# Google Talk > Gufw set to Deny/Deny does BLOCK. Please help

Tags: ufw, google-talk, gufw

I have my Ubuntu 12.04 Server. I installed Google Talk in it. I opened gufw, and set it to deny/deny and there are no allow rules.

Now firefox wont connect to the internet which is good... But... Google Talk still can send and receive text messages. Why is this? I am stumped :(

1) Here is my ufw settings (GUFW has Deny Deny clicked)

```
mathew@ubuntu:~$  sudo ufw status
Status: Active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
51413/tcp                  DENY        Anywhere
51413/udp                  DENY        Anywhere
443/tcp                    DENY        Anywhere
6881/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
6881/udp                   DENY        Anywhere
2234:2239/tcp              DENY        Anywhere
2242/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
2240/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
4444/udp                   DENY        Anywhere
6881:6891/tcp              DENY        Anywhere
6881:6891/udp              DENY        Anywhere
4662/tcp                   DENY        Anywhere
4672/udp                   DENY        Anywhere
53                         DENY        Anywhere
CUPS                       DENY        Anywher
```

Comment: You need to post all your rules. In addition, is google talk already running ? If so, it is likely an established connection.

Comment: How do i post my rules with ufw. Sorry I dont know the command. What should I run?

Comment: Here is my netstat:    mathew@ubuntu:~$ sudo netstat -tulanp
    Active Internet connections (servers and established)
    Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign     tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:53            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      4074/dnsmasq    
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1903/vmware-authdla
    tcp        0      0 192.168.100.206:538     272.242.90.146:80       CLOSE_WAIT  1886/vmnet-natd 
    tcp        0      0 192.168.100.206:65